# Filter by condition if string contains certain substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe full of emails. Knowing that gmail has a 6 character minimum I want to filter my dataframe by getting rid of any gmail address that has a username of less than six characters. Therefore, the dataframe `df`

```
>> print(df)

        email          
1   a@gmail.com             
2   real.email@gmail.com      
3   no.email@email.com        
4   real@yahoo.com              
5   poo@gmail.com
```

would become:

```
        email                     
2   real.email@gmail.com      
3   no.email@email.com        
4   real@yahoo.com
```

Using

```
df = df[
        (len(df['email'].str.split('@').str[0]) >= 6)
        (df['email'].str.split('@').str[1] == 'gmail.com')
       ]
```

will filter everything that isn't @gmail.com, so I can't use that. What I want is essentially (which obviously doesn't work and gives a `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`)

```
if df['email'].str.split['@'].str[1] == 'gmail.com':
    len(df['email'].str.split['@'].str[0]) >= 6
```

How do I accomplish this in a vectorized operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```py
df=df.loc[~df.email.str.contains(r"^.{0,5}@gmail\.com$")]
```

Outputs:

```py
                  email
1  real.email@gmail.com
2    no.email@email.com
3        real@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
a = df['email'].str.contains('gmail') #check if email has gmail
b = df['email'].str.split('@').str[0].str.len().gt(6) #check if length before "@" > 6
out = df[a&b|~a]
```

---

```
print(out)

                  email
2  real.email@gmail.com
3    no.email@email.com
4        real@yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 1):

See this:

```
>>> df[(df["email"].str.split("@").str[0].str.len() >= 6) | (df["email"].str.split("@").str[1] != 'gmail.com')]
                  email
1  real.email@gmail.com
2    no.email@email.com
3        real@yahoo.com
```

Regarding you saying "will filter everything that isn't @gmail.com", it is not correct. You just need to make your boolean logic right (like above). Also to measure the string length in dataframe, you should use `.str.len()` but not taking `len` of the whole dataframe output, which the latter will be the size of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to store the index in a list and then display just those indices:

```py
ls=[]
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if df['email'][i].split('@')[1] == 'gmail.com':
        if len(df['email'][i].split('@')[0]) >= 6:
            ls.append(i)

df[df.index.isin(ls)]
```

**Output:**

```py
                  email
1  real.email@gmail.com
2    no.email@email.com
3        real@yahoo.com
```